# How do you visualize a nondescript function with its derivative or antiderivative?

Tags: calculus

When I see a function with a description like $f(x) = x^2$ then I can visualize its graph with the graph of its derivative $2x$ or its antiderivative $\frac{x^3}{3}$.

But when I see a function without a description as in the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus like $F'(x) = f(x)$ then I have a hard time visualizing $F'(x)$ with respect to $f(x)$. This makes it difficult to keep track of what is the derivative or what is the antiderivative.

So, how do you visualize nondescript functions as in $F'(x) = f(x)$?

Comment: I don't know about visualizing the function itself but it might help that the capital letter typically used for an antiderivative like $F(x)$ often represents greater values than the corresponding lower case derivative like $f(x)$. For example, if $F(x) = x^2$ then $f(x) = 2x$ but if $F(x) = \sin x$ then $f(x) = \cos x$; so this is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

The slope equals the altitude of the point. The farther away the point is from the x-axis, the greater the slope, the closer the point is to the x-axis, the smaller the slope.